# Setting overflow: scroll on a table with display: flex

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

I have a table with the `display: flex` property, whose cells will be centered vertically. When there are more cells than the table can show, the `overflow: scroll` property doesn't take the top ones into account.

In the sample code below, the scroll stops at the letter K when it should go all the way up to the letter A. What is causing this?

```css
#container {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

td {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td></tr>
    <tr><td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    <tr><td>H</td></tr>
    <tr><td>I</td></tr>
    <tr><td>J</td></tr>
    <tr><td>K</td></tr>
    <tr><td>L</td></tr>
    <tr><td>M</td></tr>
    <tr><td>N</td></tr>
    <tr><td>O</td></tr>
    <tr><td>P</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S</td></tr>
    <tr><td>T</td></tr>
    <tr><td>U</td></tr>
    <tr><td>V</td></tr>
    <tr><td>W</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the calculation of row positions is being performed first, and any content overflowing the top edge is getting ignored. Quite peculiar. I'm not familiar enough with flexbox to explain why this happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable), browsers must wrap the `<tr>` elements inside a `<tbody>` element if there isn't any:

[image: <tbody> is inserted inside <table> (http://jsfiddle.net/ed9msnfp/)]

The height of that `<tbody>` will be the height of all rows. However, the height of the `<table>` can be smaller. That wouldn't be a problem in a table layout, because the height of the table would be treated as a minimum height.

However, the `<table>` now participates in a flex layout, not a table layout. Since the `<tbody>` is a `table-row-group` element whose parent is neither a `table` nor `inline-table` (it's a `flex`), an [anonymous](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) `table` parent is generated.

[image: The <tbody> is wrapped in an anonymous table (http://jsfiddle.net/1wf1hu0d/)]

So now we have a `<table>` which is a flex container with a single flex line, and which contains a single flex item (the anonymous `table`).

The height of the flex line will be the height of the flex container ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-cross-line)):

> If the flex container is [single-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#single_line) and has a definite cross
>   size, the cross size of the flex line is the flex container’s inner
>   cross size.

And then you use `align-items: center`. That will align vertically the anonymous `table` (together with the `<tbody>`) at the middle of the flex line, even if it overflows above or below.

The problem is that scrollbars allow scrolling to see the content that overflows below, but not the content that overflows above.

Therefore, instead of `align-items: center`, I suggest [aligning with auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins):

> Prior to alignment via [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) and [`align-self`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self),
>   any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that
>   dimension.

Note the difference: auto margins only distribute **positive** free space, not negative one.

Therefore, we only have to style the flex item with

```css
margin: auto 0; /* Push to the center (vertically) */
```

But there is a problem: as explained above, the flex item is an anonymous generated element, so we can't select it with CSS selectors.

To solve that, we can add `display: block` to the `<tbody>`. Then, it won't be wrapped in any anonymous `table` element, so it will be a flex item and the alignment will work.

Note this won't break the table, because the bunch of `<tr>`s, which are `table-row`s, will generate an anonymous `table` parent, but now inside the `<tbody>`:

[image: An anonymous table is generated inside <tbody> (http://jsfiddle.net/bvjvd30u/)]

So you can use this code:

```css
tbody {
  display: block; /* Disable tabular layout, and make <tbody> a flex item */
  margin: auto 0; /* Push to the center (vertically) */
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
tbody {
  display: block; /* Disable tabular layout, and make <tbody> a flex item */
  margin: auto 0; /* Push to the center (vertically) */
}
td {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#container div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A</td></tr>
      <tr><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C</td></tr>
      <tr><td>D</td></tr>
      <tr><td>E</td></tr>
      <tr><td>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td></tr>
      <tr><td>H</td></tr>
      <tr><td>I</td></tr>
      <tr><td>J</td></tr>
      <tr><td>K</td></tr>
      <tr><td>L</td></tr>
      <tr><td>M</td></tr>
      <tr><td>N</td></tr>
      <tr><td>O</td></tr>
      <tr><td>P</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
      <tr><td>R</td></tr>
      <tr><td>S</td></tr>
      <tr><td>T</td></tr>
      <tr><td>U</td></tr>
      <tr><td>V</td></tr>
      <tr><td>W</td></tr>
      <tr><td>X</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A</td></tr>
      <tr><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>C</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Oriol - great answer in quick time. :) I was trying same way but somehow i was trying more options for `display` parameter for tbody and took a while to get it working `block` display.

Comment: Note: the CSS working group decided to change the behavior. Now the tbody should be blockified instead of generate an anonymous parent. See details in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34601022/1529630).

Answer (score 1):

Please visit - https://jsfiddle.net/3y80zqzc/1/

You will observe newly added class for `tbody`. **margin parameter** is most important which ensures vertically middle position for the content.

```
margin: auto, 0; /*this is for vertically middle position*/
margin: 0, auto; /*this is for horizontally center position*/
```

You may also look at the HTML code

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
#container {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

td {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container div {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
tbody {
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td></tr>
    <tr><td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    <tr><td>H</td></tr>
    <tr><td>I</td></tr>
    <tr><td>J</td></tr>
    <tr><td>K</td></tr>
    <tr><td>L</td></tr>
    <tr><td>M</td></tr>
    <tr><td>N</td></tr>
    <tr><td>O</td></tr>
    <tr><td>P</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Q</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R</td></tr>
    <tr><td>S</td></tr>
    <tr><td>T</td></tr>
    <tr><td>U</td></tr>
    <tr><td>V</td></tr>
    <tr><td>W</td></tr>
    <tr><td>X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Z</td></tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```