# Wrap text in stretchable tables

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have two tables on either side of a centered div. I'd like the content in the left-hand table to be aligned on the right, and the content in the right-hand table to be aligned on the left. I managed to do so by creating an extra column in the left-hand table and setting `width: 100%` on the first cells and `white-space: nowrap` on the second cells.

The problem is, because of the `nowrap` property, the content overflows when the tables are too small. I tried setting `word-wrap: break-word` in vain. How can I force the content to fit the table width?

Here is my code so far: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6yrp73yy/)

```css
#container {
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}

table {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
}

td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#left td:nth-child(1){
   width: 100%;
}

#left td:nth-child(2) {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#list, #center {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="list"></div>
    <table id="left">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Valar morghulis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <table id="right">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>
            <tr><td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Would you kindly help me out</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Alpha</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Bravo</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Charlie</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Delta</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Echo</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Foxtrot</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Golf</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very confusing because you changed the table to flexbox in CSS, it no longer acts like real table anymore I think.

Comment: @Pangloss I set `display: block` on the tbody to counter that. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851336/setting-overflow-scroll-on-a-table-with-display-flex)

Comment: I wonder you want it like this - https://jsfiddle.net/6yrp73yy/2/ is it?

Comment: @Pangloss Both columns in your left-hand table are the same width. The first column shouldn't take more space than needed, just enough to push the second column to the right.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, can't the empty tds be removed? - https://jsfiddle.net/6yrp73yy/3/ If you need to adjust the text alignment just use `text-align` property.

Comment: @Pangloss I edited [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yrp73yy/4/) so you can see where the initial problem lies. If you stretch the container's width, you'll see the left-hand table's content looks like it is aligned with the first placeholder. In my post I added an extra column so the table's content would align itself with the second placeholder, and that is the result I want. However, when doing so, the content no longer wraps itself and that is what I am trying to resolve.

Comment: Well, I wish I could suggest more, but problem is I'm having a hard time to understand what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6yrp73yy/5/)

Remove the extra column and add `margin-left:auto` to left `tbody`

Remove the nowrap

```
#left tbody{
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to break the long words (Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) so they don't overflow? `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't work for me.

Comment: You won't be able to get it to work with `display:flex` on the the table. It's a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136818

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to align flex items inside the flex container along the main axis.

- [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)

  > The [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) property aligns [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) along the
  >   [main axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-axis) of the current line of the flex container. This is done
  >   after any flexible lengths and any [auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) have been
  >   resolved.

  ```css
  #left {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #container {
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
  }
  table {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
  }
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  #left {
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container">
    <table id="left">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Valar morghulis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="right">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Would you kindly help me out</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Alpha</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bravo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Charlie</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Delta</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Echo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Foxtrot</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Golf</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  ```
- [`flex-direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-direction)

  > The [`flex-direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-direction) property specifies how [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) are
  >   placed in the flex container, by setting the direction of the flex
  >   container’s [main axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-axis). This determines the direction that flex
  >   items are laid out in.

  If you use `row-reverse` (or `column-reverse`) instead of `row` (or `column`), you will swap the [main-start](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main_start) and [main-end](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main_end) directions.

  ```css
  #left {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #container {
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
  }
  table {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
  }
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  #left {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container">
    <table id="left">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Valar morghulis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="right">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Would you kindly help me out</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Alpha</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bravo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Charlie</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Delta</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Echo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Foxtrot</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Golf</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  ```
- [Auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

  > Prior to alignment via [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) and [`align-self`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self),
  >   any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that
  >   dimension.

  ```css
  #left > tbody {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #container {
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
  }
  table {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
  }
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  #left > tbody {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container">
    <table id="left">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Valar morghulis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="right">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Would you kindly help me out</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Alpha</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bravo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Charlie</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Delta</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Echo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Foxtrot</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Golf</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  ```
- Inserting pseudo-elements with a positive [flex grow factor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-grow-factor)

  > The *flex grow factor* determines how much the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) will
  >   grow relative to the rest of the [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) in the flex
  >   container when positive free space is distributed.

  ```css
  #left::before {
    content: '';
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  #container {
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
  }
  table {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
  }
  tbody {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
  }
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  #left::before {
    content: '';
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="container">
    <table id="left">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Valar morghulis</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="right">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Would you kindly help me out</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Alpha</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bravo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Charlie</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Delta</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Echo</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Foxtrot</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Golf</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  ```